# Extending (inheriting) from built-in class `Error`

Tags: javascript, inheritance, built-in

I try to write my own `HTTPError` object in JS. My code looks as follows

```js
"use strict"; 

HTTPError.prototype = Object.create( Error.prototype );
HTTPError.prototype.constructor = HTTPError;

function HTTPError( msg, httpStatus, httpStatusText, fileName, lineNumber )  {
  var _httpStatus = httpStatus;
  var _httpStatusText = httpStatusText;

  // Public and privileged methods

  this.httpStatus = function() {
    return _httpStatus;
  }

  this.httpStatusText = function() {
    return _httpStatusText;
  }

  // C'tor starts here
  Error.call( this, msg, fileName, lineNumber );
  this.name = "HTTPError";
}

HTTPError.prototype.toString = function() {
  var name = this.name;
  name = (typeof name !== "string") ? 'HTTPError' : name;

  var msg = this.message;
  console.log( "This is msg: " + msg );
  msg = (typeof msg !== "string") ? '' : msg;

  var status = '(Status: ' + this.httpStatus() + ' - ' + this.httpStatusText() + ')';

  if (name === '') {
    return msg + ' ' + status;
  }
  if (msg === '') {
    return name + ' ' + status;
  }

  return name + ': ' + msg + ' ' + status;
}
```

The method `toString` was inspired by [MDN Error.toString reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/toString). The signature of the `Error`-constructor is taken from [MDN Error reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

The problem is that the `toString()` method never prints the error message. The line of code `console.log( "This is msg: " + msg )` solely exists for debugging purposes. This line reveals that `msg` is undefined, hence it is set to `''`. But why is it undefined? For some reason the `message` property does not seem to be exist but I called the parent `Error` constructor. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing a major component here. In JS all objects are based from `Object`. You need to override Object. Read [The Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/toString) `carefully`

Comment: @EddieB: No, the above is perfectly standard and normal JavaScript derivation with constructor fucntions. The problem is it just doesn't work with `Error`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: What does "it just doesn't work with `Error`" mean? Do you want to tell me that `Error` does not behave like a normal JS object and therefore cannot be used as a parent object?

Comment: @user2690527 Please See [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EdwardBeckett/sut5fvsc/2/)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what do you mean it doesn't work? It works fine when I run it.

Comment: @EddieB: Sorry, I interpreted your choosing to `alert(HTTPError)` and it showing the code. (WHy would you do that rather than `alert(new HTTPError("We see this message"));`?!?!) Yes, that's the closest you can come, again see the linked question and its answers. It's not inheritance, but it can serve a lot of the same purpose.

Comment: @user2690527 Working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EdwardBeckett/sut5fvsc/6/)

Comment: @EddieB: Yes, or ***again*** in the answers on the linked question. No need whatsoever to recover this ground.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes... I see exactly what you mean now. The error is never 'extended' it's always of type 'Error.'